# Making a safe buffer holder in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

There are situations in which I need to pass a `char*` buffer back and forth. My idea is to create an object which can hold the object that owns the data, but also expose the data as `char*` for someone to read. Since this object holds the owner, there are no memory leaks because the owner is destructed with the object when it's no longer necessary.

I came with the implementation below, in which we have a segfault that I explain why it happens. In fact it's something that I know how to fix but it's something that my class kinda lured me into doing. So I consider what I've done to be not good and maybe there's a better way of doing this in C++ that is safer.

Please take a look at my class that holds the buffer owner and also holds the raw pointer to that buffer. I used `GenericObjectHolder` to be something that holds the owner for me, without my `Buffer` class being parametrized by this owner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

//The library:
class GenericObjectHolder
{
public:
    GenericObjectHolder()
    {
    }

    virtual ~GenericObjectHolder() {
        
    };
};

template <class T, class Holder = GenericObjectHolder>
class Buffer final
{
public:
    //Ownership WILL be passed to this object
    static Buffer fromOwned(T rawBuffer, size_t size)
    {
        return Buffer(std::make_unique<T>(rawBuffer), size);
    }

    //Creates a buffer from an object that holds the buffer
    //ownership and saves the object too so it's only destructed
    //when this buffer itself is destructed
    static Buffer fromObject(T rawBuffer, size_t size, Holder *holder)
    {
        return Buffer(rawBuffer, std::make_unique<T>(rawBuffer), size, holder);
    }

    //Allocates a new buffer with a size
    static Buffer allocate(size_t size)
    {
        return Buffer(std::make_unique<T>(new T[size]), size);
    }

    ~Buffer()
    {
        if (_holder)
            delete _holder;
    }

    virtual T data()
    {
        return _rawBuffer;
    }

    virtual size_t size() const
    {
        return _size;
    }

    Buffer(T rawBuffer, std::unique_ptr<T> buffer, size_t size)
    {
        _rawBuffer = rawBuffer;
        _buffer = std::move(buffer);
        _size = size;
    }

    Buffer(T rawBuffer, std::unique_ptr<T> buffer, size_t size, Holder *holder)
    {
        _rawBuffer = rawBuffer;
        _buffer = std::move(buffer);
        _size = size;
        _holder = holder;
    }


    Buffer(const Buffer &other)
        : _size(other._size),
          _holder(other._holder),
          _buffer(std::make_unique<T>(*other._buffer)) 
    {
    }


private:
    Holder *_holder;
    T _rawBuffer;
    std::unique_ptr<T> _buffer;
    size_t _size = 0;
};

//Usage:
template <class T>
class MyHolder : public GenericObjectHolder
{
public:
    MyHolder(T t) : t(t)
    {
    }

    ~MyHolder()
    {
    }

private:
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    std::queue<Buffer<const char*, MyHolder<std::string>>> queue;
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
    {
        //This string is going to be deleted, but `MyHolder` will still hold
        //its buffer
        std::string s("hello");
        auto h = new MyHolder<std::string>(s);
    
        auto b = Buffer<const char*, MyHolder<std::string>>::fromObject(s.c_str(),s.size(), h);
        queue.emplace(b);
    }
    {
        auto b = queue.front();
        //We try to print the buffer from a deleted string, segfault
        printf(b.data());
        printf("\n");
    }
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

As you see, the `s` string is copied inside the object holder but gets destructed right after it. So when I try to access the raw buffer that `buffer` owns I get a segfault.

Of course I could simply copy the buffer from the `s` string into a new buffer inside my object, but It'd be inefficient.

Maybe there's a better way of doing such thing or maybe there's even something ready in C++ that does what I need.

PS: string is just an example. In pratice I could be dealing with any type of object that owns a `char*` buffer.

Live example: https://repl.it/repls/IncredibleHomelySdk

Comment: You failed to implement a user-defined assignment operator for `Buffer`.

Comment: It seems that in `Buffer<T>`, `T` is meant to be the pointer type; `Buffer<char*>` is meant to represent an array of `char`, not of `char*`. In light of this, `std::unique_ptr<T> _buffer` doesn't make any sense (you are allocating a `char*` pointer on the heap, then make it point to the same data as `_rawBuffer`; the destructor will deallocate just that one pointer, not the buffer - the buffer will leak). Neither does `new T[size]` (it allocates an array of `char*` pointers, not an array of `char`). Despite the comment to the contrary, `Buffer::fromOwned` does not in fact take ownership.

Comment: The three-parameter `Buffer` constructor doesn't initialize `_holder` member; it contains random garbage. The destructor then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: *"//This string is going to be deleted, but `MyHolder` will still hold its buffer"* False. `MyHolder` makes a copy of its parameter. Then you create an instance of `Buffer` that points to the data from `s`, not that from `h->t`. This whole arrangement doesn't make any sense to me - you are passing `MyHolder` to `Buffer`, which doesn't really use it in any way. Whatever `Buffer` is meant to achieve, it doesn't do that.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use `char *` instead of, say, `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`?

Answer (score 6):

Your core problem is that you want your Holder to be moveable. But when the Owner object moves, the buffer object might also move. That will invalidate your pointer. You can avoid that by putting the owner in a fixed heap location via `unique_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

template <class B, class Owner>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(std::unique_ptr<Owner>&& owner, B buf, size_t size) :
      _owner(std::move(owner)), _buf(std::move(buf)), _size(size)
    {}

    B data() { return _buf; }
    size_t size() { return _size; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Owner> _owner;
    B _buf;
    size_t _size;
};

//Allocates a new buffer with a size
template<typename T>
Buffer<T*, T[]> alloc_buffer(size_t size) {
    auto buf = std::make_unique<T[]>(size);
    return {std::move(buf), buf.get(), size};
}
```

Here's a repl link: https://repl.it/repls/TemporalFreshApi

---

If you want to have a type-erased Buffer, you can do that like this:

```
template <class B>
class Buffer
{
public:
    virtual ~Buffer() = default;
    B* data() { return _buf; }
    size_t size() { return _size; }

protected:
    Buffer(B* buf, size_t size) : 
      _buf(buf), _size(size) {};
    B* _buf;
    size_t _size;
};


template <class B, class Owner>
class BufferImpl : public Buffer<B>
{
public:
    BufferImpl(std::unique_ptr<Owner>&& owner, B* buf, size_t size) :
      Buffer<B>(buf, size), _owner(std::move(owner))
    {}
    
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Owner> _owner;
};

//Allocates a new buffer with a size
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Buffer<T>> alloc_buffer(size_t size) {
    auto buf = std::make_unique<T[]>(size);
    return std::make_unique<BufferImpl<T, T[]>>(std::move(buf), buf.get(), size);
}
```

Again, repl link: https://repl.it/repls/YouthfulBoringSoftware#main.cpp

Comment: I like this answer, but it does not encapsulate an already created buffer. If I receive a giant string from somewhere else, I cannot put an already created string inside of it, or can I? On the example you make a variable called `z` but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Another problem is that now, a class that accepts a `Buffer` would have to be parametrized in the `Owner`, which would add a parameter to lots of things in the code. `Owner` should be invisible to the users of the `Buffer`

Comment: It can of course encapsulate an already created buffer. It can only encapsulate a buffer that you actually own – that the whole point. Why do you think that is not the case? I added Owner type erasure to the code.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Can you elaborate what you are missing in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> There are situations in which I need to pass a char* buffer back and
> forth.

*and*

> So I consider what I've done to be not good and maybe there's a better
> way of doing this in C++ that is safer.

It's not exactly clear what you are aiming at, but when I have this need i will sometimes use `std::vector<char>` - a `std::vector` (and `std::string`) is a just that: a managed buffer. Calling `data()` on vector will give you a raw pointer to the buffer to pass on to legacy interfaces etc. or for whatever reason you just need a buffer that you manage yourself. **Hint:** use `resize()` or constructor to allocate the buffer.

So you see, there's no need to store the internal pointer of `std::string` in your example. Instead just call `data()` on a need basis.

---

It seems like you are concerned about copies and efficiency. If you use objects that support *move semantics* *and* you use the *emplace family* of functions there shouldn't be any copy-ing going on at least in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). All/most containers supports moving as well.

Comment: the problem of using `std::vector` is that I need to copy the data to the inside of it, and I'm trying to avoid copies

Answer (score 0):

The class std::unique_ptr is already a "buffer holder" that "guarantee delete", no string copies, no dangling references and no seg faults:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> queue;
    std::cout << "begin" << std::endl;
    {
        auto h = std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello");
        queue.emplace( std::move(h) ); // move into the queue without copy
    }
    {
        auto b = std::move(queue.front());  // move out from queue without copy
        std::cout << *b << std::endl;
    }  // when b goes out of scope it delete the string
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/neP838